# Maven plugin in Eclipse - Settings.xml file is missing

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, maven-3

I installed the maven plugin for eclipse. Then tried updating the index and got the following error:

Unable to update index for central|http://repo1.maven.org/maven2

While trying to edit the proxy settings through windows-preferences-maven-user settings, I realise there is no such file. I don't have separate maven installation and only the plugin. Please someone could help resolving the problem? Thank you very much.

Cheers
A

Config: Helios Service Release 1
org.maven.ide.eclipse.feature (0.12.0.20101115-1102) "Maven Integration for Eclipse"

Comment: Even though it's been a few years, @SeanPatrickFloyd's answer is still correct and helpful - it should be accepted.

Answer (score 84):

The settings file is never created automatically, you must create it yourself, whether you use embedded or "real" maven.

Create it at the following location `<your home folder>/.m2/settings.xml`
e.g. `C:\Users\YourUserName\.m2\settings.xml` on Windows or `/home/YourUserName/.m2/settings.xml` on Linux

Here's an empty skeleton you can use:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <localRepository/>
  <interactiveMode/>
  <usePluginRegistry/>
  <offline/>
  <pluginGroups/>
  <servers/>
  <mirrors/>
  <proxies/>
  <profiles/>
  <activeProfiles/>
</settings>
```

If you use Eclipse to edit it, it will give you auto-completion when editing it.

And here's the [Maven settings.xml Reference page](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html)

Comment: Thank you. I am going through maven settings.xml reference page and it looks like a separate project on its own. :) Is there a quick way I can get going (trying not to loose focus on what I am doing with REST).

Comment: @user566930: If you just want to edit proxies, delete everything else. all elements are optional in settings.xml

Comment: Thanks. I am getting the following error: 
!ENTRY org.maven.ide.eclipse 4 0 2011-01-07 15:56:38.809
!MESSAGE Unable to update index for central|http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
!STACK 0
java.io.IOException: Server returned status code 403: Forbidden.

Comment: I think the eclipse does not cross the proxy using the info provided in settings.xml. I tried changing the credentials and same err remains. So 403 is not from repo1.maven.org/maven2 site.

Comment: *"The settings file is never created automatically"*. Thank you for confirming this. This got me really confused.

Comment: does one need to reference settings.xml in pom.xml?!

Comment: @Ewoks no, in fact your pom.xml should never reference a settings.xml. A pom.xml is a project-specific config, shared with your team, settings.xml is your personal config (not shared)

Answer (score 1):

Working on Mac I followed the answer of Sean Patrick Floyd placing a settings.xml like above in my user folder **/Users/user/.m2/**

But this did not help. So I opened a Terminal and did a **ls -la** on the folder. This was showing

```
-rw-r--r--@
```

thus *staff* and *everone* can at least read the file. So I wondered if the message isn't wrong and if the real cause is the lack of write permissions. I set the file to:

```
-rw-r--rw-@
```

This did it. The message disappeared.