# Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

When I am try to build the project it gives this error.

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'ProjectName'.
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
```

My Java version is 1.8 and Maven version is 3.2.5

And also when I first time configure Maven in my computer and I check that Maven configured correctly with `mvn --version` command and it works fine.
But after restart my computer and checked Maven is work correctly.
Then it says:

```
C:\Users\User Name>mvn --version
'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try the following steps:

1. Make sure you have connectivity (you can browse) (This kind of error is usually due to connectivity with Internet)
2. Download Maven and unzip it
3. Create a `JAVA_HOME` System Variable
4. Create an `M2_HOME` System Variable
5. Add `%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%M2_HOME%\bin;` to your `PATH` variable
6. Open a command window `cmd`. Check: `mvn -v`
7. If you have a proxy, you will need to configure it

http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html

8. Make sure you have `.m2/repository` (erase all the folders and files below)
9. If you are going to use Eclipse, You will need to create the `settings.xml`

[Maven plugin in Eclipse - Settings.xml file is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626609/maven-plugin-in-eclipse-settings-xml-file-is-missing)

You can see more detail in

http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.5/maven-settings/settings.html

Comment: How do I get to know that I am using proxy.
when I type just localhost in the browser it show me IIS 8 home page.
(with out strat xampp)
Is this matters ??
@Fernando

Comment: You can run the command "ipconfig /all". This command show you "Primary DNS Suffix" and ""DNS Suffix Search List"" Also if you have a computer from your company, look your browser, for instance, IE you go: Tools > Internet Options > Connections > LAN settings > Proxy server

Comment: There is no proxy in my computer.
I am very confuse now

Comment: If you do not use proxy you will not need to configure it.

Comment: NoughT I have just edited to write more detail. Make sure you did everything

Comment: There is no proxy and the path is properly configured.

Answer (score 4):

Delete all files under the .m2 repository folder and rebuild the project.

Comment: Fixed the issue for me, after 2-3 hours of looking for a solution plausibly helpful to my situation. I'd recommend trying this before trying or reading anything more complicated, in case it fixes it, like it did for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following :

1. Make sure you add `M2_HOME` variable to your environment variables. It looks like you might have set `M2_HOME` temporarily in a `cmd` window and not as a permanent environment variable. Also append `M2_HOME` to the `PATH` variable.
2. Go to the `m2` folder in your user directory.

   Example: On Windows, for user `bot`, the `.m2` directory will be under `C:\Users\bot`. Look for the `settings.xml` file in this directory and look for the repository url within this file. See if you are able to hit this url from your browser. If not, you probably need to point to a different maven repository or use a proxy.
3. If you are able to hit the repository url from the browser, then check if the repository contains the `maven-resource-plugin` version 2.6. This can be found by navigating to `org.apache.maven.plugins` folder in the browser. It's possible that your `pom` has hard-coded the dependency of the plugin to 2.6 but it is not available in the repository. This can be fixed by changing the depndency version to the one available in the repository.

Comment: I follow this tutorial to install maven....

[Maven in Windows](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-install-maven-in-windows/)

Comment: I found the .m2 folder but there is no settings.xml file.
What should I do??
@bot

Comment: look this question about the settings.xml: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308079/why-maven-settings-xml-file-is-not-there

Answer (score 2):

Try update your Eclipse with the newest Maven repository as follows:

1. Open "Install" dialog box by choosing "Help/Install New Software..." in Eclipse
2. Insert following link into "Work with:" input box
   http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/

   and press Enter
3. Select (check) "Maven Integration for Eclipse" and choose "Next >" button
4. Continue with the installation, confirm the License agreement, let the installation download what is necessary
5. After successful installation you should restart Eclipse
6. Your project should be loaded without Maven-related errors now

Answer (score 0):

This helped me:
I created a new maven project which was working fine in my old workspace, but gave above errors in the new workspace. I had to do the following:
 - Open old workspace on Eclipse
 - open Preferences tab
 - Search Maven in filter
 - Copy the path for settings.xml from User Settings - User Settings
 - Switch to new workspace
 - Update the preferences - Maven - User Settings - User Settings path

After the build is completed, all errors are resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in **spring tool suite(sts)**. THE .m2 repository was not completely downloaded in the local system which is the reason why I was getting this error. So I reinstalled **sts** and deleted the old .m2 repository from the system and created a new **maven** project in **sts** which downloaded the complete .m2 repository. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Step1: Delete all instances of java from you machine

Step2: Delete all the environment variables related to java/jdk/jre

Step3: Check in programm files and program files(X86) folder, there should not be java folder.

Step4: Install java again.

Step5: Go to cmd and type "java -version"
Result: it will display the java version which is installed in your machine.

Step6: now delete all the files which are in C:/User/AdminOrUserNameofYourMachine/.m2 folder

Step6: go to cmd and run "mvn -v"
Result: It will display the Apache maven version installed on your machine

Step7: Now Rebuild your project.

This worked for me.