# While making maven project I am getting "could not calculate build plan" plugins error

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, maven-plugin

I am trying to make a new project in maven, but while making the project I am getting "could not calculate build path": plugins error because of this I am not able to work further.

Steps to reproduce:
Launch Eclipse (I am using oxygen) new version
Go to File ->New ->project->select maven as project option
Enter the required filed for POM file
Now, as maven project start building, I am getting the error.

Please find attached screenshot for the reference.

[image: Maven build error]

Comment: There is no screenshot in the question. Also could you try executing `mvn clean` on the directory of the project.

Comment: I have added the screenshot @nullpointer

Comment: Could you share the plugin tags from the pom.xml that might be created at the top level project directory as well?

Comment: <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>    @nullpointer

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps:

1. Make sure you have connectivity (you can browse) (This kind of error is usually due to connectivity with Internet)
2. Download Maven and unzip it
3. Create a `JAVA_HOME` System Variable
4. Create an `M2_HOME` System Variable
5. Add `%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%M2_HOME%\bin;` to your `PATH` variable
6. Open a command window `cmd`. Check: `mvn -v`
7. If you have a proxy, you will need to configure it

http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html

8. Make sure you have `.m2/repository` (erase all the folders and files below)
9. If you are going to use Eclipse, You will need to create the `settings.xml`

[Maven plugin in Eclipse - Settings.xml file is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626609/maven-plugin-in-eclipse-settings-xml-file-is-missing)

You can see more detail in

http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.5/maven-settings/settings.html